# Задание диапазона значений через валидатор для Qt LineEdit

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, range

В Qt для lineEdit нужно задать диапазон значений целых чисел, который может быть введен пользователем. Использую QtIntValidator, но он работает странно, как будто ограничивает не значением, а количеством символов.

Например, нужен диапазон 0 - 5. Однако после сборки проекта в lineEdit можно ввести любое число с 0 до 9.
Как сделать так, чтобы вводимые значения можно было все-таки ограничить диапазоном? Значения пробовал передавать и через конструктор, и через метод setRange, результат одинаковый.
Решение выпадающий список не подходит, т.к. диапазон может быть очень большой.

Да, через регулярные выражения можно это решить, но почему валидатор так работает?

```
(конструктор MainWindow)

    QIntValidator* testvalidator = new QIntValidator(0,5, this);
    ui->lineEdit_bla->setValidator(testvalidator);
```

Comment: какой есть, там ещё есть `QLineEdit::hasAcceptableInput` можно его проверять после каждого нажатия, я в случае ошибки фон на красный меняю и запрещаю кнопку OK

Comment: А чем QSpinBox не угодил https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qspinbox.html?

Comment: тем, что выпадающий список долго прорисовывается и проматывается на несколько тысяч значений

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить класс `QValidator` или `QIntValidator`, реализовать в нем свой метод `validate`, а затем через метод `setValidator` передать его в `QLineEdit`.